# php parse error passing variable from form to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

So im using an HTML form to post information to php and then sending it to database using a php script. But i keep getting this parse error for unexpected variable (t_variable) for $first_name. Here is my code

```
<?php

 $first_name = $_POST ['firstname'];
 $last_name = $_POST ['lastname'];
 $email  = $_POST ['email'];

 $db_host = "localhost";   
 $db_username = "root";
 $db_pass = "password";
 $db_name = "db_name";

 //connect to database
 @mysql_connect ("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die ("Unable to connect to        database at the moment. Please try again later.") ; 

 //select the database to work with 
 @mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("No such database");


 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, first, last, email) VALUES ('', "$first_name", "$last_name", "$email") " ); 

 ?>
```

field types in phpmyadmin 
id is INT (25 length) - auto incremented so no need to supply it.
everything else is varchar (255 length)

NOTE: I have hardcoded the values and it worked, just doesnt work when i try passing variables. Also i have tried variables without quotations and it did not work.

How do i fix this?

Thanks

FIXED!!! the single quotes around parameters worked. Also removed the id field since its auto incrementing. Also looking at mysqli now. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: All of your code needs work. **DO NOT** suppress errors using `@`; it's like putting duct tape over your Check Engine Light. `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Have you looked at any examples? Also, that's a problem you wouldn't have with any of the non-dated database APIs and bound parameters.

Comment: Change your double quotes to singles in `VALUES ('', "$first_name", "$last_name", "$email")`

Comment: `"$db_name"` is fine but, to be on the safe side, you should do this: `(string)strval("$db_name")`.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I am looking at mysqli as well but my professor wants us to use mysql and then do it in mysqli again (NO IDEA WHY). And the single quotes did the trick! thanks

Comment: just an FYI, if your ID is autoincrementing, you don't need it in your INSERT statement

Comment: If single quotes did the trick, then why did you accept another method? @user3037373 anyway, the important thing is that it worked for you. I'm not a points monger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the quotes.  A very simple example:

```
"foo"$variable"bar"
```

This is simply invalid PHP syntax.  What you could do is:

```
VALUES ('', " . $first_name . "
```

using concatenation, `.`.

You could also use interpolation:

```
VALUES ('', $first_name,
```

However, you really shouldn't do this since your query is vulnerable to injection.  It may not even work without apostrophes surrounding the values.

You should be using properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli instead of using `ext/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php

 $first_name = $_POST ['firstname'];
 $last_name = $_POST ['lastname'];
 $email  = $_POST ['email'];

 $db_host = "localhost";   
 $db_username = "root";
 $db_pass = "password";
 $db_name = "db_name";

 //connect to database
 @mysql_connect ($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die ("Unable to connect to        database at the moment. Please try again later.") ; 

 //select the database to work with 
 @mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("No such database");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, first, last, email) VALUES (null, '".$first_name"', '".$last_name."', '".$email."') " ); 

 ?>
```

Still there is error debug errors using `var_dump(queries);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate strings, but you have not told PHP to do so! Contatenating is done like this:

> $new_string = $string1 . $string2
>
> ```
>                    ˆ this indicates you are "summing" two strings
> ```

So, in your code you should have done something like the following:

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, first, last, email) VALUES ('', '".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$email."') " );

**Important**: This code contains several exploits! Someone could easily inject SQL code and have full access to your database! See more about escaping your strings before appending them to the query. You can do it using `mysql_real_escape_string` (http://www.php.net/function.mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: One should not use `mysql_real_escape_string` (as also stated on the linked `PHP` manual).

Comment: Because the whole extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5... But that's not the case here, but I agree, PDO is a much much much better way of handling SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else said so far is true, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. But I would also add that I think you should take out the ID portion of the insert completely. And Here is why: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

So the insert statement would look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO Users (first,last,email) VALUES ($first_Name,$Last_Name,$Email)
```

Aside from that I'd follow @Janak Prajapati's example, but do keep in mind that unless this is a school project you should do more to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes in your query and add single quotes.Because when u specify `varchar()` type data you should use single quote or it may flash a parse error.This will work fine.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, first, last, email) VALUES ('', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email') " );
```